# Ошибка при работе приложения

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-8.0

Странные вещи происходят. При работе программы на определенной строчке появляется ошибка, но когда прогоняю через отладку все работает как часы. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: В том, что при отладке во время "стопа" на бряке - успевают прилететь данные из асинхронного запроса, а без отладке и стопарения на бряке - соответственно не успевают и прога крашится на пустых данных

Comment: Читать про гонку потоков (Race Condition), совершенно нормальное явление в многопоточке. Имея достаточно опыта, разработчики избегают гонок на этапе написания кода, без особого труда. Пока не покажете код, что-либо еще здесь сказать невозможно.